# Window function implementation as a SQL query

Tags: sql

How can I implement :

```
AVG(X) OVER(PARTITION BY SegmentId) AS AvgX
```

In a SQL query without using `AVG(X)`?

I can only support sum, count, min, max, but not `AVG`.

Thanks,

Or.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the one for the database you are really using.  `AVG()` is supported as a window function by all databases (that I know of) that support window functions.

Comment: is this homework or do you have problems with some entity framework?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, `AVG(X)` can be replaced by `SUM(X) / COUNT(X)`

Is this answer an oversimplification of the problem at hand?

Answer (score 1):

This returns the same results, although the context is unclear..

```
SUM(X) OVER(PARTITION BY SegmentId) / COUNT(X) OVER(PARTITION BY SegmentId)  AS AvgX
```